# First-order logic: How to determine if a formula has a finite or an infinite model

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Let $\sigma = \{ E \}$ be a signature with a binary relational symbol $E$. Does the following $[\sigma]$-formula have a finite model? Does it have an infinite model?
> $$\varphi := \forall x \exists y (E(x,y) \land \forall z ( z \neq y \rightarrow \neg E(x,z))) \land \forall x \forall y \forall z (E(x,z) \land E(y,z) \rightarrow x = y) \land \exists x \forall y \neg E(y,x)$$

I'm not sure how to approach this question and don't know where to start, can someone give me a hint or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried rephrasing each of the three conjuncts of $\varphi$ into natural language?

Comment: Hint: the first conjunct says that $E$ is equivalent to a function, i.e. there is unofficially some function $f$ from the domain of discourse to itself such that $E(x,y)$ is equivalent to $y = f(x)$.  Then, the second conjunct implies that the function is injective, and the third conjuct implies that the function is not surjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

An $E$ structure is just a graph where $E(x,y)$ says there is a (directed!) edge from $x$ to $y$.

So what does $\varphi$ say? If we can translate it into english, then we can do some combinatorics to see if it has finite or infinite models.

$\varphi$ breaks up into a conjunction of $3$ pieces. Let's look at each of them in turn.

1. $\forall x . \exists y . E(x,y) \land \forall z (z \neq y \to \lnot E(x,z))$

This says every $x$ sees a vertex $y$, and moreover if $z \neq y$, then $x$ *doesn't* see $z$.

So this says that every $x$ is $E$ related to *exactly one* vertex $y$ (do you see why?). If you like, we can phrase this as "each vertex has exactly one outgoing edge".

2. $\forall x,y,z . E(x,z) \land E(y,z) \to x=y$

This says if $x$ and $y$ both see $z$, then actually $x=y$. Graph theoretically, this says "every vertex has at most one incoming edge" (do you see why?).

3. $\exists x . \forall y . \lnot E(y,x)$

This says that some $x$ has no incoming edges (again, do you see why?).

---

So now we know what we're looking for! A model of $\varphi$ is a (directed) graph such that

1. Every vertex has exactly $1$ outgoing edge
2. Every vertex has at most $1$ incoming edge
3. At least one vertex has *no* incoming edges

Now I turn the question back to you:

> Does this have a finite model? What about an infinite model?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Dang, beat me to it.

Comment: I've been working on my typing speed ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Am I right in thinking that the formula has an infinite model but no finite model?

Comment: Exactly right! ^_^